# asymptotic function of function graph: $ y=\frac{{{x}^{x+1}}}{{{(x+1)}^{x}}}$

Tags: analytic-spread

Find the asymptotic function of the function graph:
$$y=\frac{{{x}^{x+1}}}{{{(x+1)}^{x}}}$$

Please, help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Write $$\frac{x^{x+1}}{(x+1)^x}=x\frac{x^x}{(x+1)^x}=\frac{x}{\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x}$$